# Why d and s orbitals overlap even when there is considerable difference in their energies?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, molecular-orbital-theory, orbitals, hybridization

In my grade 11 chemistry NCERT textbook, its written that hybridization happens when orbitals of almost same energy overlaps.
But S orbital and D orbital have significant difference in their energies. But still they overlap .I would be grateful to know why it happens then.

Comment: 4s and 3d are particularly close in energy values this is a major factor in transition metals which frequently (In the context of VBT) undergo hybridisation with these orbitals. What you might be mistaking about must be the energy levels of s and d of same shells which do have significant energy gaps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In multielectronic atoms we have a relatively large difference between $s$ and $d$ orbitals **when they have the same $n$ quantum number**, or in terms of the actual quantum mechanics when they have the same total number of nodes in the wavefunction (this being what we label as $n-1$). But in the case of transition metals the $s$ orbital that mixes in with the $d$ orbitals has **one higher $n$ or equivalently one more total node** -- for instance, with iron it would be $\color{blue}{4}s$ (three total nodes) mixing with $\color{blue}{3}d$ (two total nodes). The opposing differences between angular momentum and between total nodal count leave the relevant orbitals close together in energy.

Comment: ok i am satisfied with ur answer, thanks